# Как закрыть прямой доступ к txt-файлу на сайте?

Tags: php, .htaccess

На сайте есть текстовый файл *site.com/php/contacts.txt*. Если открыть этот файл в браузере, то виден весь текст файла. Как закрыть доступ к файлу, чтобы можно было просматривать его только на сервере, но не через браузер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При помощи файла `.htaccess` это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^php/contacts.txt$ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Этот вариант работает только в том случае, если папка PHP лежит в корне?

Comment: Этот - да. Только если папка в корне.

Comment: более заморочливый способ: разместить файл выше корня. для этого возможно придется редактировать код (если код каким-то образом контактирует с этим файлом).

Comment: RewriteRule ^page/php/contacts.txt$ - [R=404,L] ???

Comment: У меня почему-то не работает http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/php/contacts.txt даже в корне

Comment: @ВикторПавлов Упс... Пардон. Это работает не только для корня, но и для любого подкаталога. Если бы было `^/php/contacts.txt$`, то только для корня.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов Может быть, хостинг не обрабатывает `.htaccess`?

Comment: Разве такое возможно, чтобы не обрабатывал?

Comment: @ВикторПавлов В настройках *Apache* можно установить запрет на обработку `.htaccess`. Это делает директива `AllowOverride None`.

Comment: Это прописывается также в .htaccess?

Comment: @ВикторПавлов Нет. Это прописывается в конфигурационных файлах *Apache*.

Answer (score 0):

При помощи файла .htaccess это можно сделать следующим образом (Версия 2):

```
<Files php/contacts.txt>
Deny from all
</Files>
```